# Transform counter data

Tags: powershell, performancecounter

I have the following script:

```
$SqlServerCounterPrefix = '\MSSQL$MSSQL_2008'
$Data = get-counter ($SqlServerCounterPrefix + ":Buffer Manager\Buffer cache hit ratio"), 
                    ($SqlServerCounterPrefix + ":Buffer Manager\Page life expectancy"), 
                    ($SqlServerCounterPrefix + ":Access Methods\Page splits/sec")
#$Data
$TransformedData = $Data.CounterSamples | Select-Object -Property Path, CookedValue
$TransformedData | Add-Member -NotePropertyName 'Timestamp' -NotePropertyValue $Data.Timestamp
$TransformedData | Format-table -auto
```

This results in the following:

```
Path                                                                 CookedValue Timestamp          
----                                                                 ----------- ---------          
\\sw-pa-win10\mssql$mssql_2008:buffer manager\buffer cache hit ratio         100 2016-10-25 10:18:19
\\sw-pa-win10\mssql$mssql_2008:buffer manager\page life expectancy           123 2016-10-25 10:18:19
\\sw-pa-win10\mssql$mssql_2008:access methods\page splits/sec                  0 2016-10-25 10:18:19
```

How would i go about turning it into the following:

```
Timestamp              buffer cache hit ratio    page life expectancy    page splits/sec
---------              ----------------------    --------------------    ---------------
2016-10-25 10:18:19    100                       123                     0
```

Note: im not good with powershell so if you have any suggestions about improving the original script they are most welcome as a comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution:

```
$SqlServerCounterPrefix = '\MSSQL$MSSQL_2008'
$Data = get-counter ($SqlServerCounterPrefix + ":Buffer Manager\Buffer cache hit ratio"), 
                    ($SqlServerCounterPrefix + ":Buffer Manager\Page life expectancy"), 
                    ($SqlServerCounterPrefix + ":Access Methods\Page splits/sec")
$TransformedData = $Data.CounterSamples | Select-Object -Property Path, CookedValue

$object = New-Object psobject

$object | Add-Member -NotePropertyName 'Timestamp' -NotePropertyValue $Data.Timestamp
foreach ($row in $TransformedData)
{
    $path = $row.Path
    $name = $path.Substring($path.LastIndexOf("\") + 1)
    $object | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $name -NotePropertyValue $row.CookedValue
}
$object
```